# Jquery Test if a url already contain a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-rewriting

I know there are a lot of questions about this, but I didnt found exactly what I needed

This is the js I have

```
$j('.showCategory li a').each(function() {
    var catId = $j(this).attr("data-id");
    this.href += (/\?/.test(this.href) ? '&' : '?') + 'filter_category='+ catId;
});
```

This works great as it generate my url with the param I want. The problem is that if I click multiple times (this filter is available on all pages), it's adding the same parameter over and over, generating an url like this:

http://www.blabla.com/search?search=cat&filter_duration=short&filter_duration=medium&filter_duration=long

I tried fixing that by adding a condition like

```
$j('.showCategory li a').each(function() {
    if(this.href.indexOf('filter_category') == -1) {
        var catId = $j(this).attr("data-id");
        this.href += (/\?/.test(this.href) ? '&' : '?') + 'filter_category='+ catId;
    } else {
        ????
    }
});
```

But in that case, it's not adding any parameter, but it's not replacing the value. How can I solve this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this pattern to do an in-place replacement with a regular expression:

```
} else {
this.href = this.href.replace(/filter_duration=(.+?)(&|$.*)()/, "filter_duration=" + catId + "$2"
}
```

This uses capture groups to find an existing filter_duration element query parameter, and replaces the existing value in place with a new value (in this case catId).  This should work regardless of whether it is the last query parameter in the string or not.

That said, I wouldn't regard this solution as optimal, and you would probably be better off with storing the values that you want in your url in a client side javascript object, and then rebuild the url each time from scratch whenever anyone changes a category.  That way you won't have to worry about difficult to test cases where something goes wrong with a replacement and the client getting into a bad state.